# Plotting 2 rasters over each other on a map with 2D colour scheme

Tags: python, r, gis, postgis, arcgis

This is rather a GIS question. What I am trying to do is to make a map that would show the areas which are hot-dry, hot-wet, cold-dry, cold-wet. I have 2 rasters with precipitation and temperature values. And I want to plot them over each other so that each extreme combination of the 2 variables (hot-dry, hot-wet, cold-dry, cold-wet) would have its own colour with respective gradients for the intermediate values on the colour scheme, that will have to produce a 2D colour legend. Below please see the concept image, that I have produced for explanation. I saw such a thing once and thought that was a briliant idea to show how 2 variables interact, but then I totally forgot where it was. I have been googling for 2 days - no result. Any help is very much welcome - the name of the thing, name of the software to do it (how to do it would be marvelous), keywords to google, workarounds - anything.
[Concept image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1IH9.jpg)

Comment: Solved: http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder to myself, a possible solution could be:

```
temp <- matrix(1:10000, 100)
temp <- raster(temp)
temp[] <- scales::rescale(temp[],to = c(0,255))

pp <- t(matrix(1:10000, 100))
pp <- raster(pp)
pp[] <- scales::rescale(pp[],to = c(0,255))

constant <- pp
constant[] <- rep(255,ncell(constant))

# Here you can vary the order of the bands (1,3,2) to get different colours
plotRGB(stack(list(constant,temp,pp)),1,3,2)
```

The resulting plot looks like this (it should look better with real temperature and precipitation data):

[image: plotRGB]